# Sitting to long after fermentation

Tags: fermentation, primary-fermentation

I had brewed one gallon and I let it ferment and then let it sit... I think it has been two months or so after the recommended fermentation of this particular brew. I know it won't continue to ferment or anything but I am wondering if you just let it sit for that long does anything bad happen? Or could I just bottle it like normal and not get sick or anything!? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two months isn't all that long. Some beer styles are routinely aged for that long or even longer. You might need to add a little fresh yeast to ensure good carbonation. Other than that, you should be good to go.